# Steam games stuck in 'pre-loaded' state. How can I fix it?

Tags: steam

I've gotten some games, got almost 100+ hours on some, then my PC went through an update and now all my games say, "Pre-load complete" From what I have already read, they are in essence locked. It's been like this for a few days now, and no change has happened. My Steam is up-to-date, all my games are the latest versions, I've even uninstalled a game I wanted to restart anyway to see if that changed anything, but no. It won't even let me reinstall the game.

Can someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: "pre-load" usually indicates that the Steam account you're logged into doesn't own the game.  Are you sure Steam is logged into the account that owns these games?

Comment: Yes, the account I'm using is the one that owns the games, it's my only account

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I was an idiot and tried to sign in using a really old account I haven't used in almost three years now so don't make the mistake I did!